# Importing EXIF Face Tags into Google Photos from Other Apps

Tags: google-photos

I've read a lot about people trying to get face data out of Google Photos, which I believe is not currently possible. However many desktop applications such as Lightroom or the defunct Picasa store face data into the EXIF metadata of the JPG file so it's readable by other applications. They use the MWG standard (https://exiftool.org/TagNames/MWG.html#Regions).

I recently experienced a computer crash and I lost the application I used to use to process and upload photos. My recollection is that Google Photos used to recognize face tags of uploaded pictures. However now I'm trying to recreate the process and I can't get Google Photos to see the face regions that I've saved.

Does anyone know if Google reads this metadata?

Here is an example of the exif data from a photo I uploaded:

```
H:\Photos\Utilities>exiftool -XMP-mwg-rs:all "H:\Photos\2010-2019\2018\2018-04-02 beach vacation.jpg"
Region Applied To Dimensions H  : 3024
Region Applied To Dimensions Unit: pixel
Region Applied To Dimensions W  : 4032
Region Area H                   : 0.069775
Region Area Unit                : normalized
Region Area W                   : 0.040178
Region Area X                   : 0.274057
Region Area Y                   : 0.272817
Region Name                     : Bartholomew Schwartz
Region Type                     : Face
```